# tomcat: undeploying war file won't unload classes

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks

I'm using :

- tomcat 7.0.62
- java 1.8.65

  Suddenly i find my web application unresponsive, using jvisualVM just
  find out that the Metaspace acquired more than 3GB and loading 700K
  classes but my application only loads about 20K of classes. I've been
  deploy/undeploy my application so many times in last few days and
  suspect that would be the reason of so many loaded classes.

Should'nt tomcat unload classes by undeploying applications, Normally
or my app has a memory leak ?

P.S: Reading catalina.log saw many logs about failed to stop some threads and it would be memmory leak, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector can only collect what's not referenced any more. If your application starts threads and doesn't stop them, there's your reference.

Figure out what threads don't get stopped and make corrections so that they are. That should fix your problem.